# "Could not find a part of the path" c# IIS deployment on production

Tags: c#, iis, file-io, iis-7.5

I am loading an xml file from my applicatin:

```
XDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/") + "XMLMetadata\\Actions.1.xml");
```

In the dev environment it is working fine.

But After I deploy the application, the system cannot find it.
this is the error:
`Exception Details: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\XMLMetadata\Actions.1.xml'.`

the file was deployed to
`C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\XMLMetadata\Actions.1.xml`
**and not to:**
`C:\inetpub\wwwroot\XMLMetadata\Actions.1.xml`

ASP .NET 4 MVC APPLICATION
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to say what exact framework and base class you are working here, but I'm guessing ASP.NET. If so, you may want to have a look at `Control.ResolveUrl()`.

Then, you should get something like the following instead of your `Load()` call.

```
XDocument.Load(this.ResolveUrl("~/XMLMetadata\\Actions.1.xml"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm - do you mean to ask why it has deployed to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\XMLMetadata\` rather than `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\XMLMetadata\`?

As it is you've answered the reason why you get an error.

It is for this reason that you try and use referential URLs i.e. `~\XMLMetadata\` rather than a hard coded location.

Also ensure that you test on the development system using IIS locally.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you are looking to use the "~" in this case.  The "~" used with Server.MapPath will give you the physical path to the root of the application.  Where as "/" will give you the physical path to the root of the domain name.  These paths can be different based on how you have IIS setup.

```
XDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + "XMLMetadata\\Actions.1.xml");
```

Comment: This won't work, it will still resolve to the physical path of the root, not the virtual directory of "MyApp".

Comment: I think this is still correct as long as his website is marked as an application in IIS.  Which I assume is what is going on since it seems that is where his code is running, and the paths are different in development and production.

Answer (score 0):

I've used something like this in the past:

```
    var appPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;
    if (appPath.Substring(appPath.Length - 1, 1) != "/") appPath = appPath + "/";
    var filePath = appPath + "XMLMetaData//Actions.1.xml";
```

Comment: although as I reread your post this probably won't be useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your web application is sat in a virtual directory, so you will need to resolve to that level:

```
var applicationRoot = 
    HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(
        HttpRequest.ApplicationPath);
```

Remarks on [ApplicationPath from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.applicationpath.aspx):

> Use this property to construct a URL relative to the application root
>   from a page or Web user control that is not in the root directory.
>   This allows pages and shared controls that exist at different levels
>   of a directory structure to use the same code to link to resources at
>   fixed locations in the application.

Answer (score 0):

```
XDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("XMLMetadata/Actions.1.xml"));
```